# What to do when cairo asks to read more data than I have when creating and ImageSurface from png?

Tags: c++, png, cairo

I'm using cairomm version 1.12.0 with cairo version 1.14.6.

I'm trying to create an ImageSurface in cairo from a png which I have stored in memory as a vector of bytes.  Most of the time this is working, but sometimes Cairo passes my read function (the lambda) a length to read (length parameter) greater than what's left in the vector. When I'm debugging this in visual studio of course I get a failed debug assertion `Expression: cannot seek vector iterator after end`

```
Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::ImageSurface> someFunc(const std::vector<BYTE>& src)
{
  Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::ImageSurface> ret;
  if(src.size() > 0)
  {
    unsigned int read = 0;
    ret = Cairo::ImageSurface::create_from_png_stream([&src, &read](unsigned char* data, unsigned int length) {
      std::copy_n(src.begin() + read, length, data);
      read += length;
      return CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    });
  }
  return ret;
}
```

If I try modifying my read function to copy the minimum of the remaining data and the length Cairo has asked to read, I'm getting `CAIRO_STATUS_NO_MEMORY`, which causes a `std::bad_alloc` exception to be thrown.

```
Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::ImageSurface> someFunc(const std::vector<BYTE>& src)
{
  Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::ImageSurface> ret;
  if(src.size() > 0)
  {
    unsigned int read = 0;
    ret = Cairo::ImageSurface::create_from_png_stream([&src, &read](unsigned char* data, unsigned int length) {
      length = std::min((unsigned int)src.size() - read, length); // added
      std::copy_n(src.begin() + read, length, data);
      read += length;
      return CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    });
  }
  return ret;
}
```

I think this has something to do with the call to `_cairo_output_stream_write` in `stream_read_func` in cairo-png.c, as it passes it the same size as it passes my read func, so it is likely expecting some data to be there.

```
...
status = png_closure->read_func (png_closure->closure, data, size);
...
_cairo_output_stream_write (png_closure->png_data, data, size);
```

Should I be writing null or something to pad the difference in bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If cairo asks for more data than what you have, your PNG is broken. Cairo asks for as many bytes as libpng asks for and supposedly libpng Knows What It Is Doing (tm) and asks for the right amount of bytes. If you do not have enough bytes, you should return `CAIRO_STATUS_READ_ERROR` from your read function.

Comment: Thanks. I dumped the png into a file and inspected it in a hex editor and found that its final IDAT chunk claims to have a length of 8192 bytes, but in fact is only 7725 bytes. I'll have to add some error handling and look at why the data was lost earlier in the pipeline.